# Rails Migration, converting from string to enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

If I've got a production database that has "types" stored as string, but I want to convert that column to an integer for `enum`.

I've googled/SO'd, and I see that I can `CAST`, but not sure what that does exactly.

If it's not hard, I'd love ot use rails `enum`, but otherwise, maybe I should stick with my string schema...

Please advise!

Comment: cant you override the attribute accessors in order to read as string and then set as enum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can rename existing column, create a new one called "types" (integer), then write a script that stores appropriate integer value in the new column, and then drop the old column.

The migration will look like this:

```
class FixTypes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :table_name, :types, :old_types
    add_column :table_name, :types, :integer
  end
end
```

Then write a script that sets the value of "types" based on "old_types":

```
Model.all.each do |entry|
  entry.types = %w(status1 status2 status3 status4).index(entry.old_types)
  entry.save!
end
```

And then drop the "old_types" column.

Comment: Let's refactor, please! `entry.type = %w(status1 status2 status3 ...).index(entry.old_type)`

Comment: Thanks @BroiSatse! @Kevin Brown accepting the answer won't hurt ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I figured you can edit the migration file to update the new column with the values you want to use as enums.

It should look something like this:

```
class UpdateColumnNameInTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def up
    add_column :table_name, :new_column_name, :integer

    # Define the new enum values and their corresponding integers
    enum_values = {
      value1: 0,
      value2: 1,
      value3: 2
    }

    # Update the existing rows with the corresponding integer values
    execute <<-SQL
      UPDATE table_name SET new_column_name = #{enum_values[:value1]} WHERE column_name = 'value1';
      UPDATE table_name SET new_column_name = #{enum_values[:value2]} WHERE column_name = 'value2';
      UPDATE table_name SET new_column_name = #{enum_values[:value3]} WHERE column_name = 'value3';
    SQL

    # Define the new column as an enum
    change_column :table_name, :new_column_name, :integer, using: 'new_column_name::integer'
    add_index :table_name, :new_column_name
  end

  def down
    remove_column :table_name, :new_column_name
  end
end
```

Hope it helps!